# You need to set exactly 4 parameters on the prepared statement Error for addBatch()

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement

I am trying to add list of values in a single column of some table from mysql.
and for that I am doing this
forloop get integet val from integer valueset
            pstmt.setInt(3, val)->
            pstmt.addBatch()
once looping is done then execute the batch and then execute update
        pstmt.executeBatch()
while doing this I am getting following error here
You need to set exactly 4 parameters on the prepared statement
And this is causing at statement pstmt.addBatch()
In my current case there is only one value in values list

```
"insert into table_name (ID,Name,values,sal) VALUES (?,?,?,?)"
```

Comment: for (Integer val: values) {
            pstmt.setInt(3, val);
            pstmt.addBatch();
        }
        pstmt.executeBatch();

Comment: As the error tells, your query has 4 placeholders, so you _must_ provide a value for each of them .

Comment: What code are you calling to bind the parameters? Your statement requires 4 values so you must bind four values.

Comment: I have already provided values for other 3, and now I am trying to add multiple values in a single column